# Controlling Motor Relays via Arduino using protothreads

Tags: c, multithreading, arduino, sensors, protothread

I am working on controlling two motor relays via an arduino. The setup is the following:

Each relay is controlled by a simple switch setup. When the switch is closed, the relay is active. When the switch is open, the relay is inactive.

I decided to give protothreads a go since I want the two switches to control the motors in paralell. In order to do so, I have written the following code:

```
 #include <pt.h>

#define yMaxLimitLeft 8 //these are the limit switches that control the relays
#define yMaxLimitRight 9 //these are the limit switches that control the relays
#define leftRelay 4
#define rightRelay 5

static struct pt pt1, pt2; // each protothread needs one of these



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  PT_INIT(&pt1);  // initialise the two
  PT_INIT(&pt2);  // protothread variables
  pinMode(leftRelay, OUTPUT);  //set pins     
  pinMode(rightRelay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yMaxLimitLeft,INPUT);
  pinMode(yMaxLimitRight,INPUT);

}

void loop() {

   digitalWrite(leftRelay, HIGH);//enable relays
  digitalWrite(rightRelay, HIGH);//enable relays
   runLeft(&pt1); //protothreads that controls relay number 1
  runRight(&pt2); //protothreads that controls relay number 2

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function controls the left relay
static int runLeft(struct pt *pt) {

  PT_BEGIN(pt);

  while(1){

    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, digitalRead(yMaxLimitLeft)==HIGH); //wait until the switch is closed
     Serial.println("left off"); 
      digitalWrite(leftRelay, LOW);//disable relay

      }   

    PT_END(pt);
}


//this function controls the right relay
static int runRight(struct pt *pt) {
  PT_BEGIN(pt);

   while(1){


    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, digitalRead(yMaxLimitRight)==HIGH); //wait until the switch is closed
     Serial.println("Right off");   
     digitalWrite(rightRelay, LOW);//disable relay

    }


  PT_END(pt);
}
```

The problem is the following. As long as I press  down only one switch, the respective relay responds. However when I press down both switches, only one relay responds (presumable the one which got triggered the earliest).

How do I fix the code so that when both switches are held down, both relays respond simultaneously?

Thank you very much for your time and help in advance

Answer (score 0):

As long as the predicate in `PT_WAIT_UNTIL` (i.e. `digitalRead(yMaxLimitLeft)==HIGH`) is true, execution will be stuck in that while loop.

The code probably becomes easier to reason about if `loop()` *only* is responsible for keeping the protothreads running. If we move the initial enabling of the relays into `setup()`, `runLeft/Right` can be rewritten to contain *all* logic related to a certain switch+relay. In that case, a second `PT_WAIT_UNTIL` statement can be used to wait for the switch to open again.

```
#include <pt.h>

#define yMaxLimitLeft 8 //these are the limit switches that control the relays
#define yMaxLimitRight 9 //these are the limit switches that control the relays
#define leftRelay 4
#define rightRelay 5

static struct pt pt1, pt2; // each protothread needs one of these



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  PT_INIT(&pt1);  // initialise the two
  PT_INIT(&pt2);  // protothread variables
  pinMode(leftRelay, OUTPUT);  //set pins     
  pinMode(rightRelay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yMaxLimitLeft,INPUT);
  pinMode(yMaxLimitRight,INPUT);    

  digitalWrite(leftRelay, HIGH);//enable relays
  digitalWrite(rightRelay, HIGH);//enable relays

}

void loop() {

  runLeft(&pt1); //protothreads that controls relay number 1
  runRight(&pt2); //protothreads that controls relay number 2

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function controls the left relay
static int runLeft(struct pt *pt) {

  PT_BEGIN(pt);

  while(1) {

    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, digitalRead(yMaxLimitLeft)==HIGH); //wait until the switch is closed
    Serial.println("left off"); 
    digitalWrite(leftRelay, LOW);//disable relay

    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, digitalRead(yMaxLimitLeft)==LOW); //wait until the switch opens again
    digitalWrite(leftRelay, HIGH);//enable relay

  }   

  PT_END(pt);
}


//this function controls the right relay
static int runRight(struct pt *pt) {
  PT_BEGIN(pt);

    while(1){

      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, digitalRead(yMaxLimitRight)==HIGH); //wait until the switch is closed
      Serial.println("Right off");   
      digitalWrite(rightRelay, LOW);//disable relay

      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, digitalRead(yMaxLimitRight)==LOW); //wait until the switch opens again
      digitalWrite(rightRelay, HIGH);//enable relay
    }


  PT_END(pt);
}
```